# Не происходит подписка на событие в Start()

Tags: c#, unity3d, события

Есть метод `Build()`

```
      public void Build(CellSerializable[,] matrix)
        {
            ClearMatrix();

            CellMatrix = new GameObject[matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1)];

            var width = 1.5f;
            var height = (width / Mathf.Sqrt(3f / 4f));

            for (int i = 0; i != matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j != matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    CellMatrix[i, j] = Instantiate(Cell);

                    var cellData = CellMatrix[i, j].GetComponent<CellData>();
                    cellData.Level = matrix[i, j].Level;
                    cellData.MaxLevel = matrix[i, j].MaxLevel;
                    cellData.IsEmpty = matrix[i, j].IsEmpty;
                    cellData.PlayerOwnerId = matrix[i, j].PlayerOwnerID;

                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                        CellMatrix[i, j].transform.position = new Vector3(i * height, j * width, 0);
                    else
                        CellMatrix[i, j].transform.position = new Vector3(i * height + height / 2, j * width, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

В нем вызывается метод `Instantiate()` который создает объект префаба.
У этого префаба есть компоненты `CellData`,`CellRender`,`CellMouseControl`.

В `CellData`, при изменении полей я генерирую событие изменения: `OnChanged`.

```
    public class CellData : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public delegate void DataStateHandler();
        public event DataStateHandler OnChanged;

        private int level;
        public int Level {
            get => level;
            set
            {
                level = value;
                OnChanged();
            }
        }

        private int maxLevel;
        public int MaxLevel
        {
            get => maxLevel;
            set
            {
                maxLevel = value;
                OnChanged();
            }
        }

        private int playerOwnerId;
        public int PlayerOwnerId
        {
            get => playerOwnerId;
            set
            {
                playerOwnerId = value;
                OnChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool isEmpty;
        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            get => isEmpty;
            set
            {
                isEmpty = value;
                OnChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

В `CellRender`  я подписал метод на это событие:

```
    public class CellDataRender : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private CellData cellData;
        private UnityEngine.UI.Text oText;
        private UnityEngine.UI.Text lText;
        private UnityEngine.UI.Text mlText;
        public GameObject LevelText;
        public GameObject MaxLevelText;
        public GameObject OwnerText;
        void Start()
        {
            cellData = this.GetComponent<CellData>();
            oText = OwnerText.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
            lText = LevelText.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
            mlText = MaxLevelText.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();

            cellData.OnChanged += ShowData;
        }

        private void ShowData()
        {
            lText.text = cellData.Level.ToString();
            oText.text = cellData.PlayerOwnerId.ToString();
            mlText.text = cellData.MaxLevel.ToString();

            if (cellData.IsEmpty)
            {
                lText.text = "";
                oText.text = "";
                mlText.text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

После того как я создал объект путем `Instantiate` я пытаюсь обратиться к полям `DataCell` с целью изменить их значения, соответственно происходит вызов события `OnChanged`, но вылетает `NullReferenceException`, это значит, что на событие еще никто не подписан. Почему так происходит? Разве `Instantiate()` не вызывает методы `Start()` у всех компонентов?

Comment: Подписываться и отписываться на события лучше в методах `OnEnabled` и `OnDisabled`, насколько я помню.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При `Instantiate()`, происходит не `Start()`, а `Awake()`. `Start()` происходит перед первым `Update()` (то есть в следующем фрейме).